# how does an oracle spatial index become corrupted?

Tags: oracle, spatial-index, oracle-spatial

So I have a table with an Oracle Spatial Index. After some DMLs the index breaks. I don't know exactly when this happens. Most of the time DELETE and UPDATE statements are executed on the table. Does anyone know why the index breaks and how I can prevent this?

This is the script i use to check and repair the index:

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
  l_msg varchar2(32000);
  l_err_msg varchar2(2000);
begin
  for rec in (select SDO_INDEX_OWNER,SDO_TABLE_NAME,SDO_INDEX_NAME,SDO_RTREE_HEIGHT
    from all_sdo_index_metadata
   where SDO_INDEX_OWNER = 'OWNER'
  ) loop
    begin
      execute immediate 'SELECT count(*) FROM table(mdsys.sdo_rtree_admin.sdo_rtree_descrids(:index_owner,:index_name,:rtree_height)) A
      WHERE a.column_value NOT IN (SELECT ROWID FROM '||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_TABLE_NAME||')'
                into l_cnt using rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER, rec.SDO_INDEX_NAME, rec.SDO_RTREE_HEIGHT;
      if l_cnt > 0 then
            execute immediate 'alter index '||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_INDEX_NAME||' rebuild online';
                :txt := :txt||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_TABLE_NAME||': '||l_cnt||' Index '||rec.SDO_INDEX_NAME||' neu aufgebaut'||chr(10);
                -- l_msg := l_msg||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_TABLE_NAME||': '||l_cnt||' Index '||rec.SDO_INDEX_NAME||' neu aufgebaut'||chr(10);
          else
            :txt := :txt||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_TABLE_NAME||': '||l_cnt||chr(10);
            -- l_msg := l_msg||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_TABLE_NAME||': '||l_cnt||chr(10);
          end if;
    exception
        when others then
          l_err_msg := sqlerrm;
          --l_msg := l_msg||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_TABLE_NAME||': '||l_err_msg;
          :txt := :txt||rec.SDO_INDEX_OWNER||'.'||rec.SDO_TABLE_NAME||': '||l_err_msg||chr(10);
        end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Are there any messages in the Alert log? How about trace files in the dump directory?

Comment: can you define "breaks"? What is USER_INDEXES.STATUS ?

Comment: i've added the script i use to check and repair the index

Comment: What exact errors do you get in your application ?

Comment: ORA-13199:  Spatial Index Commit Failure. After a rebuild the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Oracle version? Your script doesn't compile in 11.2.0.4.
Also, an example of `After some DMLs the index breaks`? I've never seen a DML able to break an index.
Here's the script I've being using for years now, HTH

```
    select di.TABLE_owner, di.TABLE_NAME, di.owner idx_owner, di.INDEX_NAME, dc.column_name, 
        di.PARAMETERS, 
        di.STATUS, di.DOMIDX_STATUS, di.DOMIDX_OPSTATUS, sit.SDO_INDEX_STATUS, di.FUNCIDX_STATUS, 
        sit.sdo_index_table, sit.SDO_TABLESPACE, sit.SDO_TSNAME, sit.SDO_RTREE_SEQ_NAME, di.LAST_ANALYZED, di.NUM_ROWS, di.PARTITIONED 
   from DBA_INDEXES di, DBA_IND_COLUMNS dc, mdsys.SDO_INDEX_METADATA_TABLE sit
  where index_type = 'DOMAIN' 
    and di.TABLE_owner in ('OWNER')     --a table has an (table_)owner
    and di.owner=dc.index_owner and di.owner=sit.sdo_index_owner   --its index maybe in another owner. the index owner= col.indx.owner+sdo.indx.owner
    and di.INDEX_NAME=dc.INDEX_NAME and di.index_name= sit.sdo_INDEX_NAME --same w ind.name
    and di.table_name=dc.TABLE_NAME 
    and (di.STATUS!='VALID' or sit.SDO_INDEX_STATUS!='VALID' or di.DOMIDX_STATUS!='VALID' or di.DOMIDX_OPSTATUS!='VALID' )     
  order by di.TABLE_owner, di.TABLE_NAME, di.INDEX_NAME, dc.column_position, dc.column_name ;
```

Comment: Oracle is 19c. The DML is really like: insert into table values geomrow or delete from table where id not in (select geom_id_fk from tableB); Thats the strange part